# How to show string "All" instead number in MVC4?

Tags: string, asp.net-mvc-4, replace, numbers

I have this code, that shows how many Items you want to show per page. Instead of the last option number, I want to show a string "All" which would return all items on one page.

This is my code:

```
Items per page: @{ var arr = new[] { 10, 15, 30 };}
            @for (var i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                if (arr[i] == Model.Search.PageSize)
                {
                    <span>@arr[i]</span> 
                }
                else
                {
                    <a href="@Url.SetParameters(new { pagesize = arr[i], page = 1 })">@arr[i]</a>
                }
                @Html.Raw((i == (arr.Length - 1) ? "" : "|")) 
            }
```

Now, instead "30" I want to show a string "All" that would return all of the items on a page. I have done this:

```
@{ var test = Model.TotalCount; } //totalcount is variable, that returns number of all items.

Items per page: @{var arr = new[] {10, 15, @test };} 
...
```

Using the above, @test works, but returns number of all items.

Thanks for help

Comment: I was using this tutorial https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/blob/master/Documentation/Sample-application.md because so I used pagination of this tutorial. But thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the string (rough but effective)

```
else
{
    var linkText = (i < arr.Length -1) ? arr[i].ToString() : "All";
    <a href="@Url.SetParameters(new { pagesize = arr[i], page = 1 })">@linkText</a>
}
```